# How to monkey patch in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, monkeypatching

I want to add a method to `ActiveStorage::Blob`. I have this:

**config/initializers/active_storage_cached_urls.rb**

```rb
module ActiveStorageBlobCachedUrl
  def direct_url
    xxx || self.service_url
  end
end
```

**end of config/environment.rb**

```rb
ActiveStorage::Blob.include ActiveStorageBlobCachedUrl
```

I launched `rails s` in development, and it works. Then I updated one ruby file, such as a model, and I got an error: `undefined method 'direct_url...`.

I guess something is reloaded without my monkey patch. What am I missing in order to have my monkey patch also reloaded?

Comment: You don’t miss anything. Rails detects it should reload `ActiveStorage::Blob` and reloads it. It has no clue about it should reload somewhat else.

Comment: Thank you, I added this in order to be more precise with my question : "what am I missing in order to have my Monkey Patch also reloaded?"

Comment: You should manually apply it after reload. Define a console command to execute `reload! && ActiveStorage::Blob.include(ActiveStorageBlobCachedUrl)` and call it instead of `reload!`.

Comment: I don't even call reload! I have my rails s, it is working, and when I update user.rb, without restart my rails s, then when i reload the page it fail. I don't know where I should put `ActiveStorage::Blob.include ActiveStorageBlobCachedUrl` in order to make it work with this auto-reloading thing. I think I should not put it in environment.rb.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to teach rails to reload some other stuff when it reloads what it considers to be reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in a file in `initializers/`

```
module ActiveStorageBlobCachedUrl
  def direct_url
    # xx
  end
end


ActiveSupport::Reloader.to_prepare do
  ActiveStorage::Blob.include ActiveStorageBlobCachedUrl
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not an optimal solution, but when I put the code in **environment.rb** or in **lib/*.rb*** or in **config/initializers/.rb**, then I have the error.

If I put it one model file, then it works.

**app/models/random_model.rb**

```
ActiveStorage::Blob.include ActiveStorageBlobCachedUrl
ActiveStorage::Variant.include ActiveStorageVariantCachedUrl

class RandomModel < ApplicationRecord
  xxx
end
```